# Checking if two lists are equal in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create function `setEqual`.. This is what I have so far:

```
setEqual :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
setEqual []    _                    = True
setEqual _     []                   = False
setEqual a@(x:a') (y:b) | x == y    = setEqual a' b
                        | otherwise = setEqual a b   

setEqualTest = [ not ("ABCD" `setEqual` "ABC"),
                 not ("ABC" `setEqual` "ABCD"),
                 [0,2,1,3] `setEqual` [0,1,2,3] ]
```

When I run the test I get `[True, False, False]`. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Think about it from a mathematical standpoint. When are two lists equal? Can you state that in English terms as a definition? The first line of your current function reads in English as "the empty list is equal to all lists". The second line reads as "all lists are not equal to the empty list". Haskell is surprisingly English-like when you get the hang of it, so start by thinking about what algorithm you want to represent.

Comment: When deciding whether two *lists* represent the same *set*, there's a really useful helper function, `elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool`, which determines whether a particular value is an element of the set represented by the list. I suggest you write that first, and use it to write `setEqual`.

Comment: If you have learned about higher-order functions already, you might want to think about a second helper function, `all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`, which determines whether *all* the elements of a list satisfy the given predicate. Note that `all` is exported by the `Prelude`, so if you want to write your own you'll either have to `import Prelude hiding (all)` or give your version a different name.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I made the first line set to false and the second set to true? Still stuck

Comment: Nicole, you seem to be engaged in the common but unproductive practice of throwing code at the wall to see if anything sticks. You're never going to guess your way into the right answer. As Silvio Mayolo suggested, a good first step is to write out, in very clear language, what your function is supposed to mean, and then to write out, again in clear language, how you intend to calculate it. The actual code can come later.

Comment: Mathematically, two sets A and B are the same if the set difference A \ B is empty, and B \ A is empty as well. And of course two empty sets are equal -- that's why your first two equations are wrong right from the start.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to get two things right for writing your recursive function (to check set equality here): the base case and the recursive case.

You base case is incorrect. You don't know that an empty set `[]` is equal to an arbitrary set `_` unless it's also empty. So it should be:

```
setEqual []    []                    = True
```

plus that empty set is not equal to anything else:

```
setEqual []    _                    = False
setEqual _    []                    = False
```

(Note that the `setEqual []    [] ...` line takes precedence as it is written before the others.

Your recursive case has a typo, and the last line should be:

```
| otherwise = setEqual a' b
```

Comment: it's best to include full corrected code snippet, so as not to leave us guessing what the finished code should be. in particular, your suggestion seems to just make the two recursive sub-cases exactly the same?

Comment: .... which seems like it would make your suggestion wrong? so could you clarify?